# How do I replace defaultImageManager with PHCacheImageManager

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, phasset, photosframework

I am trying to take this [Apple Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts) and use `PHCacheImageManager` instead of the default PHImageManager.

As it stands I am not sure where to initially cache the images or where to remove the images that are no longer needed in the cache as the user scrolls through the `UICollectionView`. After setting the `imageManager` variable to a `PHCacheImageManager` I pull the intial set of assets like so

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
        if status == .authorized {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            self.fetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
            self.fetchResults?.enumerateObjects({asset, index, stop in
                self.assets.append(asset)
            })

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Reload collection view once we've determined our Photos permissions.
                print("assets count: \(self.assets.count)")
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            self.displayPhotoAccessDeniedAlert()
        }
    }
```

but I am not sure how to modify functions which will have a functionality similar to this given there is no set thumbnail size and the added and removed assets are dependent upon a users scroll. Would it be correct to place the code below in `willDisplayCell` and `didEndDisplayingCell`

```
imageManager.stopCachingImages(for: removedAssets,
                               targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
imageManager.startCachingImages(for: addedAssets,
                                   targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
```

Comment: Look at Apple's SamplePhotosApp sample code (also called ``Example app using Photos framework'').